# What is the difference between a bond and a debenture?

Tags: debt, bonds, financial-literacy

What's the difference between a **bond** and a **debenture**?

Are they simply different words used to mean the same thing? (e.g. debenture sounds more *business-like* than bond).

Answer (score 7):

Investopedia has definitions for both:

> [Debenture](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/debenture.asp): A type of debt instrument that is not secured by physical asset or collateral.
>
> [Bond](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bond.asp): A debt investment in which an investor loans money to an entity (corporate or governmental) that borrows the funds for a defined period of time at a fixed interest rate.

Wikipedia's entry for [debenture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debenture) says:

> In some countries [debenture] is used interchangeably with bond, loan stock or note.

Seems to me that there's not much difference.

Comment: I think it was used in the context of public debt in the past. A "debenture" today would be referred to as a "general obligation bond", backed by the faith & credit of the issuer. I believe that a "bond" in the past referred to a debt instrument with a lien on a specific cash flow (aka "revenue bond") or an asset (aka "mortgage bond").

Answer (score 0):

Some additional links which explain their differences. But mostly as @bstpierre says, both are very similar and in some cases the terms may be used inter changeably

- http://finance.mapsofworld.com/debenture/definition.html
- http://ezinearticles.com/?Debentures-Vs.-Stocks-And-Bonds&id=392416